# SSRS: Display field using CAST in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to display a value in the same field by using `iif` statement. But one is `INT`, another is `Decimal` and the last one is percentage. So, I `CAST` them as `varchar` in SQL. How do I display the result in SSRS field?

Here is an example:

```
IF @Choice = '1'
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       UserId, CAST(IntNum AS VarChar(10)) AS Result
    FROM Sample 
END 
ELSE IF @Choice = '2'
BEGIN
    SELECT 
       UserId, CAST(DecNum AS VarChar(10)) AS Result
    FROM Sample 
END
```

How do I display `Result` in a SSRS field?

Comment: Do you really need these displayed in one field? We have done something similar by creating three fields (columns or placeholders) in the report and hidning and showing them dynamically. If you do this, then you will get the number when you export to Excel instead of the string representing the number. This builds off of Jason's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of embedding the logic in your SQL statement, why not do it in the report since (presumably) this is where `@Choice` is defined?

**SQL:**

```
-- @Choice is not needed in this query.
SELECT UserId, IntNum, DecNum
FROM Sample
```

**Report:**

Add a Calculated Field in the field listing of your DataSet (call it `Result`):

```
=IIF(Parameters!Choice.Value = 1, Fields!IntNum.Value.ToString, Fields!DecNum.Value.ToString)
```

Now your report will have 4 fields in the DataSet:

- UserId (int)
- IntNum (int)
- DecNum (dec)
- Result (string)

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to do your logic in a CASE Statement, which is really one column, so it should work well in SSRS.

```
SELECT  UserID,
        CASE
            WHEN @Choice = 1 THEN CAST(IntNum AS VARCHAR(10))
            WHEN @Choice = 2 THEN CAST(DecNum AS VARCHAR(10))
            WHEN @Choice = 3 THEN CAST(PercentageNum AS VARCHAR(10))
        END AS Result
FROM    [Sample]
```